# Inner join on 3 tables is not working

Tags: ms-access, inner-join

I have the following data tables (please find the attached Image). [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh2k3.jpg)
I'm trying to execute a query using inner join on more than 2 tables. Following is my query, Please let me know where I'm doing the mistake.
I am using MS-Access.

```
SELECT Employees.Namee,WeekDay.DayName,Schedule.StartTime,Schedule.Hours FROM Schedule  INNER JOIN Employees ON Schedule.Emp_ID = Employees.ID  INNER JOIN  WeekDay ON Schedule.Weekday = WeekDay.ID;
```

Comment: what is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: @mangotang `Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression...`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need parentheses when you have multiple joins. Try this

```
SELECT Employees.Namee,WeekDay.DayName,Schedule.StartTime,Schedule.Hours FROM
(Schedule  INNER JOIN Employees ON Schedule.Emp_ID = Employees.ID)  INNER JOIN  
 WeekDay ON Schedule.Weekday = WeekDay.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below code**

```
SELECT e.Namee,w.DayName,s.StartTime,s.Hours 
    FROM Schedule s 
    INNER JOIN Employees e
    INNER JOIN  WeekDay w
    ON s.Emp_ID = e.ID  
    ON s.Weekday = w.ID;
```

Comment: I think there would be Name instead of Namee in Employees table.

Comment: no it is Namee because this is what is saved as name in the field.

Comment: It look like sql query, please remember Im working in Access.